# Executing JQuery after AJAX Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a page (http://littlebigclick.com/jason/showproducts.php) that uses Jquery for pagination. I also use AJAX to filter results by keyword and other criteria using a live search. The problem is that whenever the AJAX executes, I lose the pagination functionality. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific and show the part of your code which is affected, we are not psychic. Your problem can be a million different things depending on what implementation you have made

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your code (follow Martin's advice for that one) but it sounds like this may be what you're looking for: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You probably attach behaviour to the paging controls when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // attach behaviour to paging controls...
});
```

Then, when you page to the next set of results, you redraw the pagination controls on the screen - they no longer have the paging behaviour attached... Either run the code which adds the paging behaviour again, or take a look at jquery live: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    CODE TO START PAGING.
});
```

have

```
function SetUpPaging()
{
  CODE TO START PAGING.
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    SetUpPaging();
});
```

Then on your ajax success function call SetUpPaging() again.

Usign .live() is however a cleaner way to do this.